# mysql delete record from joined table

Tags: javascript, mysql, join

i am having trouble deleting a record from a mysql table that is joined to the one i'm selecting the delete from.

I execute the following delete statement by selecting a checkbox and clicking a submit button on a javascript table interface on my website that uses jos_fsdspremade.id as its autoincrement key and typical delete id.

```
DELETE jos_fsdscart.*
FROM jos_fsdscart
LEFT JOIN jos_fsdspremade ON  jos_fsdscart.mfd = jos_fsdspremade.item_number
WHERE jos_fsdspremade.id = ( '<input name="jos_fsdspremade.id" multiple="y" />' )  AND jos_fsdscart.id4 = '<code type="user" />'
```

**but nothing is deleted from jos_fsdscart**.  the log is as follows:

> Replacement value for attribute 'id' is '61'
>
> executeQuery[ start: 0, limit: 0 ] 'query1' ( )
>
> Query Code: DELETE jos_fsdscart.*
>   FROM jos_fsdscart LEFT JOIN jos_fsdspremade ON jos_fsdscart.mfd =
>   jos_fsdspremade.item_number WHERE jos_fsdspremade.id = ( '' ) AND
>   jos_fsdscart.id4 = ''

As you can see, I am trying to delete a record from the jos_fsdscart table based upon a selection from a joined table:

if it helps, here is the mysql query that i am selecting from in the javascript interface:

```
SELECT
  `<output name="jos_fsdspremade.owner_id"  hidden="y" />`,
  `<output name="jos_fsdspremade.id" title="FSDS" width="70" text="view" type="next" query="24" task="showResults" linktype="open" sizex="980" sizey="730"  />`,
  `<output name="jos_fsdspremade.item_number" title=".pdf" width="70" text="SAVE" type="link" url="/menumanager/images/pdf/%s.pdf" />` ,
  `<output name="jos_fsdspremade.pic"  title="Image" type="link" linktype="img" url="/menumanager/images/preman/%s" sizex="30" sizey="30" width="65" />`,
  `<output name="jos_fsdspremade.title" title="Product Name" width="300" filter="y" />`,
  `<output name="jos_fsdspremade.brand" title="Brand" width="300" filter="y" />`,
  `<output name="jos_fsdspremade.manufacturer" title="Distributor" width="200" filter="y"/>`,
  `<output name="jos_fsdspremade.product_type" width="200" filter="y"/>` 
FROM jos_fsdspremade, jos_fsdscart
WHERE `published`=1 AND jos_fsdscart.mfd = jos_fsdspremade.item_number AND `id4` = '<code type="user" />' 
 ORDER BY `title`
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt you have a mysql table constructed in such a way that 'id' is set to a varchar which will accept something like `("jos_fsdspremade.id" multiple="y" )`.

You need to get the ids from the form (where it appears id is selectable) and pass them to the query:

```
WHERE jos_fsdspremade.id = 1
```

Or if you want to do multipe ids:

```
WHERE jos_fsdspremade.id in (1, 2, 3)
```